# R- Computing distance with missing values

Tags: r

Assume I have two vectors :

```
x=c(1,NA,5,4)
y=c(NA,2,4,19)
```

I need to compute the pairwise distance for all non-missing values :

Output :

```
sqrt((4-5)^2+(19-4)^2)=15.0333   # desired

dist(rbind(x,y), method= "euclidean") 
         x
y 21.26029    # not desired
```

`dist(rbind(x,y), method= "euclidean")` doesn't give the wanted result !

Comment: @markus , i corrected the mistake. Thank you !

Comment: Try with `cbind` instead.

Comment: `dist(t(na.omit(cbind(x,y))))` should work (sqrt((4-5)^2+(19-4)^2))

Comment: Problem solved ! Thank you all !